# Solve in positive integers, $ x^6+x^3y^3-y^6+3xy(x^2-y^2)^2=1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Solve in positive integers, $$ x^6+x^3y^3-y^6+3xy(x^2-y^2)^2=1$$

My attempt :

$ x^3y^3+x^6-y^6+3xy(x^2-y^2)^2$

$=x^3y^3+3x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)+3xy(x^2-y^2)^2+(x^2-y^2)^3$

$=(xy+(x^2-y^2))^3$

$=(x^2+xy-y^2)^3 = 1$

so $x^2+xy-y^2 = 1$

Please suggest how to proceed.

---

Thank you, AmateurMathGuy and lhf.

Please check my work on Induction for Fibonacci sequence.

$$t_{k+2}-3t_{k+1}+t_{k}=0$$
$$y_{k+2}-3y_{k+1}+y_{k}=0$$

$(t_1,y_1)=(3,1)\to(x_1,y_1)=(1,1)$

$(t_2,y_2)=(7,3)\to(x_2,y_2)=(2,3)$

$(t_3,y_3)=(18,8)\to(x_3,y_3)=(5,8)$

$(t_4,y_4)=(47,21)\to(x_4,y_4)=(13,21)$

Since $1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21$ are in Fibonacci sequence, we predict that $(x_n,y_n)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n})$

and will prove by Induction.

$(x_n,y_n)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n})$ is true for $n=1, 2, 3, 4$

Suppose that $(x_k,y_k)=(F_{2k-1},F_{2k})$ is true,

Since $y_{k+1}-3y_k+y_{k-1}=0$, so $y_{k+1}=3y_k-y_{k-1}=3F_{2k}-F_{2k-2}$

$=3F_{2k}-(F_{2k}-F_{2k-1})=2F_{2k}+F_{2k-1}=F_{2k}+F_{2k+1}=F_{2k+2}$

$x_{k+1}=\frac{t_{k+1}-y_{k+1}}{2}=\frac{(3t_k-t_k)-3y_{k-1}-y_{k-1}}{2}$

$=3\left(\frac{t_k-y_k}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{t_k-1-y_{k-1}}{2}\right)=3x_k-x_{k-1}$

Similarly, $x_{k+1}=F_{2k+1}$, so $(x_n,y_n)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n})$

Answer : $(x_n,y_n)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n})$

Comment: I think there's a mistake on the second line - there should be a negative sign in front of the second term.

Comment: Solve the last equation for $x$ using the quadratic formula and you'll find $y$ in https://oeis.org/A001906.

Comment: @B.Mehta. I don't see the mistake.

Comment: @carat Ah yes, I'd been misreading. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite Solutions:

$$x_k=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{5} \cdot \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  + \frac{5-\sqrt 5}{5} \cdot \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k\right]$$

$$y_k=\frac{5+3\sqrt 5}{10} \cdot \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  + \frac{5-3\sqrt 5}{10} \cdot \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k$$

But you've done all the hard work yourself,

$$xy+x^2-y^2=1 \  \to$$

$$\left(2x+y\right)^2 - 5y^2 = 4$$

when you complete the square.

So we arrive at a simple pell like equation, one with infinite solutions:

$$\text{let}  \  \  \  \ t=2x+y \ \to$$
$$t^2-5y^2=4 \tag{*}\ \ \to$$
$$\left(\frac{3t+5y}{2}\right)^2-5\left(\frac{t+3y}{2}\right)^2=4 \  \to$$
$$\begin{cases} t_{k+1}=\frac{3}{2}t_{k}+\frac{5}{2}y_{k} &&& (1)\\ y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}t_{k}+\frac{3}{2}y_{k} &&& (2)\end{cases}  \ \ \ \to$$

$\underline{(t,y)\to\left(x=\frac{t-y}{2},y\right)}$

$(3,1) \ \to (1,1)$

$(7,3) \ \to (2,3)$

$(18,8) \ \to (5,8)$

$(47,21) \ \to (13,21)$

$ \vdots$

To solve this system $((1) , (2))$ first we can eliminate $y_{k}$:

$$\frac{3}{2}t_{k+1}-\frac{5}{2}y_{k+1}=t_{k}$$
$$\frac{5}{2}y_{k+1}=\frac{3}{2}t_{k+1}-t_{k}$$

Step the recurrence down, so that you can substitute:

$$\frac{5}{2}y_{k}=\frac{3}{2}t_{k}-t_{k-1}$$

Substitute for $\frac{5}{2}y_{k}$ from $(1)$

$$\left(t_{k+1}-\frac{3}{2}t_{k}\right)=\frac{3}{2}t_{k}-t_{k-1}$$

$$t_{k+1}-3t_{k}+t_{k-1}=0$$
Step back up, and here you have a second order linear recurrence relation in just one variable:

$$t_{k+2}-3t_{k+1}+t_{k}=0$$
$$y_{k+2}-3y_{k+1}+y_{k}=0$$

Indeed, you get the same thing solving for $y$.  Although it's the same recurrence relation the first and second values may differ, producing different sequences for $t$ and $y$.  You solve one, we'll do $t$ here, and repeat the process to solve the other.

Proceeding with t, anyone who has studied the Fibonacci sequence knows the historical "guess".  You "guess" that $t_k=\lambda^k$.

$$\lambda^{k+2}-3\lambda^{k+1}+\lambda^k=0$$
Let's assume $\lambda\neq0$, then divide through by $\lambda^k$:
$$\lambda^2-3\lambda+1=0$$
Leads us to
$$\lambda_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$\lambda_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
We use this to update our guess to something in the span of $\lambda_1^k$ and $\lambda_2^k$:

$$t_k=A\cdot\lambda_1^k+B\cdot\lambda_2^k$$

And we can find out what $A$ and $B$ are by using the first and second solution to $(*)$ which are $(3,1)$ and $(7,3)$; we can let $t_0=3$ and $t_1=7$, thus:

$$\begin{cases} A+B=3 \\ A\cdot \lambda_1 + B \cdot \lambda_2 = 7 \end{cases}$$

This time, with matrix notation, we have that

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&1&3\\
  \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & 7
  \end{array}\right) 
\sim 
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1 & 0 & \frac{7-3\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}\\
  0 & 1 & \frac{3\lambda_1 - 7}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}
  \end{array}\right)$$

Thus
$$A=\frac{7-3\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}=\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}$$
$$B=\frac{3\lambda_1 - 7}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}=\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}$$

Repeat the process for $y$, finding the $A$ and $B$ for $y$, and our second order recurrences have been solved:

$$t_k=\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  + \frac{3-\sqrt5}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k$$

$$y_k=\frac{5+3\sqrt 5}{10} \cdot \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  + \frac{5-3\sqrt 5}{10} \cdot \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k$$

Our original substitutions were

$t=2x+y \implies x_k = \frac{t_k - y_k}{2} $

finally leading us to

$$x_k=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{5} \cdot \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  + \frac{5-\sqrt 5}{5} \cdot \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k\right]$$

$$y_k=\frac{5+3\sqrt 5}{10} \cdot \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k  + \frac{5-3\sqrt 5}{10} \cdot \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k$$

Comment: $$(t_1,y_1)=(3,1)\to(x_1,y_1)=(1,1)$$

$$(t_2,y_2)=(7,3)\to(x_2,y_2)=(2,3)$$

$$(t_3,y_3)=(18,8)\to(x_3,y_3)=(5,8)$$

$$(t_4,y_4)=(47,21)\to(x_4,y_4)=(13,21)$$

$1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21$ are numbers in Fibonacci sequence, please suggest how to proceed

Comment: Will do today..

Comment: @carat Thanks for asking such a cool question

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:***

You should keep the cube

$$(x^2+xy-y^2)^3 = 1$$

$$(x^2+xy-y^2)^3 -1^3 = 0$$

You should factorize with the formula $a^3-b^3= (a-b) (a² + ab + b²))$

*Edit:* 
Then solve the equations.But as pointed by Alex, $ a^2+a=-1$ has no solution in $ Z $, so only $a=1$ need to be solved.

Comment: If $Z$ is an integer, and $Z^3=1$, then $Z=1$. There is no need to consider the equation coming from your second factor, $Z^2+Z+1=0$ because it has no integer solutions. So you are getting to the same place OP gets.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that $(1,1)$ is one of solutions.

Let $y-1=m(x-1)$ be an equation of the line which has other solutions.

Hence, $m\in\mathbb Q$ and after substitution in $x^2+xy-y^2=1$ we obtain:
$$x=\frac{m^2-2m+2}{m^2-m-1}$$ and
$$y=\frac{2m-1}{m^2-m-1}.$$
I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

[Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities)  for the Fibonacci numbers is
$$
F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F_{n}^{2}=(-1)^{n}
$$
Therefore
$$
1
=F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1}-F_{2n}^{2}
=F_{2n-1}(F_{2n-1}+F_{2n})-F_{2n}^{2}
=F_{2n-1}^2+F_{2n-1}F_{2n}-F_{2n}^{2}
$$
and $x=F_{2n-1}$, $y=F_{2n}$ are solutions of $x^2+xy-y^2 = 1$.

Similarly,
$$
F_{2n-1}^2-F_{2n-1}F_{2n-2}-F_{2n-2}^{2} = 1
$$
and $x=-F_{2n-1}$, $y=F_{2n-2}$ are solutions of $x^2+xy-y^2 = 1$. But the OP only wants positive solutions.

It remains to prove that these are the only solutions.

Comment: Will you please check if there is any mistake in my work above ? Looking forward to see your reply.

Comment: @carat, perhaps you could move your solution to an answer.

Comment: Yeah !  Thank you all :))